# Download Test Run Results from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, manual-testing

We are using the Azure DevOps Test Plan module for our manual testing. We have a Test Plan, under which, we have Test Suite, under which we have Test Cases that are assigned to different Testers. Testers use ADO to mark a Test Case outcome as passed or fail.

We want to download the Test Case outcome/results, but I don't see that option. We have a Test Run tab under Test Plan which shows all Run outcomes but doesn't give the option to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps to download the Test Run results from ADO –

1. Navigate to Test Plan -> Runs
2. Click on filters, remove all filters and run the query
3. Click on one result and press Ctrl + A and then Ctrl + C
4. Paste the content in Notepad++, then copy the content from Notepad++ and paste it Excel.
5. This will give you list of all Test Runs with results. You can get the latest outcome of test run, by sorting data using Run ID in descending order and then using unique rows only.

Comment: You can accept your answer. This will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly export the test results of test runs to excel.

To meet your requirement, you can use Rest API to list all required test runs and test results. Then you can export them to Excel.

You can use the following two Rest APIs:

Get Test Runs: [Runs - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate={minLastUpdatedDate}&maxLastUpdatedDate={maxLastUpdatedDate}&state={state}&planIds={planIds}&isAutomated={isAutomated}&publishContext={publishContext}&buildIds={buildIds}&buildDefIds={buildDefIds}&branchName={branchName}&releaseIds={releaseIds}&releaseDefIds={releaseDefIds}&releaseEnvIds={releaseEnvIds}&releaseEnvDefIds={releaseEnvDefIds}&runTitle={runTitle}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&api-version=7.0
```

Get Test Results:  [Results - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?detailsToInclude={detailsToInclude}&$skip={$skip}&$top={$top}&outcomes={outcomes}&api-version=7.0
```

Here is PowerShell sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url=" https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_apis/test/runs?api-version=7.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

echo $response

ForEach( $testrunid in $response.value.id ) 
{
  echo $testrunid
  $url1 ="https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_apis/test/Runs/$($testrunid)/results?api-version=7.0"
  $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
  
  ForEach( $testresult in $response1.value) 
  {
     $outcome = $testresult.outcome
     $startedDate = $testresult.startedDate
     $testCase =$testresult.testCase.name
     $completedDate = $testresult.completedDate
     $testCaseTitle = $testresult.testCaseTitle
     echo $outcome
     echo $startedDate
     $Output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    outcome = $outcome
    runid =$testrunid
    startedDate = $startedDate
    completedDate= $completedDate
    testCase = $testCase 
    testCaseTitle = $testCaseTitle
   } | Select-Object runid, outcome,startedDate,testCase,testCaseTitle,completedDate
$Output | Export-Csv C:\testresult.csv -Append

  }
   
}
```

You can customize the output excel column according to your requirements.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but sad that such basic feature is not there out of the box, I however found a workaround to download it from the UI itself.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta. Can you share your workaround to download the result?

Comment: Below are the steps to download the Test Run results from ADO – 

1) Navigate to Test Plan -> Runs
2) Click on filters, remove all filters and run the query
3) Click on one result and press Ctrl + A and then Ctrl + C
4) Paste the content in Notepad++, then copy the content from Notepad++ and paste it Excel.
5) This will give you list of all Test Runs with results. You can get the latest outcome of test run, by sorting data using Run ID in descending order and then using unique rows only.

Answer (score 0):

You could Export the test plan properties, test suite properties along with details of the test cases and test points as either an email or print to pdf by using the **Export** function of the test suite: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/navigate-test-plans?view=azure-devops#test-suites-context-menu-options)

Make sure you have [test access and permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops) in Azure DevOps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this just exports in a printable format. I was looking for a query based format or an excel format, which I can use to build my report on. Any help?